# Windows authentication failing on one machine only

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, iis-7, internet-explorer-8, windows-authentication

I have a windows machine trying to access the IIS server that has windows authentication turned on. I know this works on the server side as I had logged into my domain account on one other machine, and others in my unit are able to access the url in question without the need to log in (browser does that automatically).

I'm stumped as to my my own development machine is unable to log in that way (and still displays a login box) and would like some assistance, or at least a few ideas of what else to check.

I have checked tools -> internet options -> security -> local intranet -> advanced options -> user authentication, where it is set to provide username and password automatically.

My workstation is windows 7 enterprise, like the others in the office, though as a developer I don't doubt I changed some setting on the client I didn't need to.

Any ideas?

Update: If it matters any, it also fails in Chrome without the login box at all, just a simple "Error 10 (net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED): Unknown error"

Comment: When you visit the site, did you see it shown as local intranet or Internet in IE status bar at the bottom?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have faced similar problem with the chrome and was not able to open any intranet websites . I did everything to solve it but nothing worked got really frustrated. Finally came across to the above post. By looking at the lines

> I have checked tools -> internet options -> security -> local intranet -> advanced options -> user authentication, where it is set to provide username and password automatically.

got some clue. I was curious what is the username and password used if we check the 'automatic username and password' box and exactly this was what was the solution.

The automatic username and password is taken from Windows Vault(Search for "Manage Network Password" inside Control Panel). In my case there was an entry in the Windows Credentials category. This was the username and password which was used in case we have checked the 'automatic username and password' box in the tools -> internet options -> security -> local intranet -> advanced options -> user authentication.

So the solution is either correct that entry or remove that entry altogether if you are sure that you don't require it elsewhere.

Comment: Sadly that was one of the things I had checked, so for this PARTICULAR question this wasn't the solution. But, it is good information to check. BUT, Damned good find, I didn't know about the vault before. Now that's one more thing I can check if this problem surfaces in the future.

Comment: +1 removing stored credentials from vault solved my problem. after entering wrong password windows/chrome didn't bother to show pwd dialog again.

Comment: This plus restarting Chrome (including the background process mentioned below by matao below did the trick for me

Answer (score 4):

Chrome share security settings of IE. Open your page in IE, go to tools -> internet options --> security tab --> Local intranet --> Sites --> Advanced --> Add this website to the zone field --> Input the web site you are trying to visit which is throwing ERR_ACCESS_DENIED error including the right protocol which you are using like http or https and click Add button
In Security tab, continue to make sure Intranet Zone is highlighted and click on custom level button
Under the (last) section User Authentication, make sure you select following option:
Automatic logon only in Intranet Zone

If you are logged on to the domain and your web site is using Integrated windows authentication, then this resolution will work and you will be able to get rid of ERR_ACCESS_DENIED.

After this if it does not work, clear your browser following items from browser cache:
Cookies and other site and plugin data
Cached images and files

Restart browser.

If it does not work, restart your machine.

"For me restating machine helped"

If it still does not work change "Automatic logon only in Intranet Zone" setting back to "Prompt for user name and password" in IE options and restart your browsers and retry.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Chrome saves certain credentials in Windows Credential Vault (start | search for Manage Windows Credentials) you will see your credentials there. Delete the credential and you will be prompted for fresh creds.

Answer (score 1):

Just leaving this here for posterity, I just had the same problem after visiting a site using NTLM and accidentally using the old password. clearing cache/cookies etc had no effect, restarting Chrome had no effect, I was at a dead end.

Then I realised that because of the Chrome launcher, I had processes running in the background, so I killed them and after that everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem.

The solution was to close all instances of Chrome.

I changed my Windows password yesterday.  Chrome must have been caching something related to that old password.